# how to configure email notification in jenkins?

Tags: email, jenkins

i have a local set up of Jenkins in my windows machine. 
tried adding the e-mail ext plugin but the error as in the attachment is displayed.

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/email-ext/2.44/email-ext.hpi
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1153)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1650)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1848)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1624)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/email-ext/2.44/email-ext.hpi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

so manually downloaded the .hpi and added it to the plugin's folder
still am not able to see the e-mail notification section and the action under post-build action steps.

navigated to manage jenkins-> configure system-> email notification section is not displayed

Comment: please give some screenshot so clearly understand your problem.

Comment: @NectarM- there is no section as email notification in jenkins setup for me. and am not able to restart it manually too after adding the dependencies.Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured. is displayed

Answer (score 1):

please install the **dependency** **plugin**  & try.
(Matrix-project, config-file-provider, mailer, workflow-step-api, junit, analysis-core, token-macro, workflow-job).

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

[image]

Comment: am not able to restart jenkins after adding all the above:Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured. is displayed on using http://25.163.2.201:9090/restart

Comment: Stop the jenkins server, Download all hpi & copy in plugin folders, start again. it wil work. you cannot do restart for individual dependency plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are blocked by the corporate proxy, the best thing would be to find a way to authenticate with the corporate proxy (if you aren't, I am not sure if Jenkins proxy supports NTLM out of the box), or find out how to get access to the Jenkins plugin centre rather than download all the plugins and it's dependencies manually.

If you need to authenticate using NTLM, it might be a good idea to either:

1. Install Jenkins as a service and run the service as yourself
2. Use Cntlm to have a platform & tool agnostic way of authenticating using NTLM.